# Powershell: Editing Firefox Prefs.js file

Tags: firefox, powershell

I'm trying to update the Firefox Prefs.js file and I am stuck:

```
#Sets up a bogus (0.0.0.0) proxy for FireFox
#Modfies the following settings in Firefox's pref.js configuration file:

#user_pref("network.proxy.http", "0.0.0.0");
#user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", 80);
#user_pref("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8");

#locate the prefs.js files
$PrefsFiles = Get-Item -Path ($env:SystemDrive+"\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\prefs.js")

$out = $PrefsFiles.FullName + ".new"
#Read in the content
$Prefsjs = (Get-Content $PrefsFiles)

$Prefsjs -replace 'user_pref\(\"network.proxy.http\".+', 'user_pref("network.proxy.http", "0.0.0.0");'
$Prefsjs -replace 'user_pref\(\"network.proxy.http.port\".+', 'user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", 80);'
$Prefsjs -replace 'user_pref\(\"network.proxy.http.no_proxies\".+', 'user_pref("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost, 127.1.1.1, 192.1.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8");'
Set-Content $PrefsFiles
```

While the above code seems to make the desired changes. (I can see the contents of the file in the command window and the changes are there.) The file ends up blank.

I tried a different approach and it goes into an infinite loop:

```
#Sets up a bogus (0.0.0.0) proxy for FireFox
#Modfies the following settings in Firefox's pref.js configuration file:

#user_pref("network.proxy.http", "0.0.0.0");
#user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", 80);
#user_pref("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8");

#locate the prefs.js files
$PrefsFiles = Get-Item -Path ($env:SystemDrive+"\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\prefs.js")

$out = $PrefsFiles.FullName + ".new"

(Get-Content $PrefsFiles) | ForEach-Object{

$_ -replace 'user_pref\(\"network.proxy.http\".+', 'user_pref("network.proxy.http", "0.0.0.0");'
$_ -replace 'user_pref\(\"network.proxy.http.port\".+', 'user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", 80);'
$_ -replace 'user_pref\(\"network.proxy.http.no_proxies\".+', 'user_pref("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost, 127.1.1.1, 192.1.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8");'
} | Set-Content $out
```

I know I'm close but I just can't seem to get set-content to write the output to the file. The infinite loop in the second attempt is puzzling:  There is no loop...

I tried to pattern my code based on the examples I've seen online but they just don't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a slightly different approach and got it to work:

```
﻿#read in the prefs file
#locate the prefs.js files
$PrefsFiles = Get-Item -Path ($env:SystemDrive+"\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\prefs.js")
$out = @()
$out2 = @()

#clear screen
clear

#load changes
$Update= 'user_pref("network.proxy.backup.ftp", "0.0.0.0");
user_pref("network.proxy.backup.ftp_port", 80);
user_pref("network.proxy.backup.socks", "0.0.0.0");
user_pref("network.proxy.backup.socks_port", 80);
user_pref("network.proxy.backup.ssl", "0.0.0.0");
user_pref("network.proxy.backup.ssl_port", 80);
user_pref("network.proxy.ftp", "0.0.0.0");
user_pref("network.proxy.ftp_port", 80);
user_pref("network.proxy.http", "0.0.0.0");
user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", 80);
user_pref("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost,    127.0.0.1,10.0.0.0/8,192.0.0.0/8");
user_pref("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings", true);
user_pref("network.proxy.socks", "0.0.0.0");
user_pref("network.proxy.socks_port", 80);
user_pref("network.proxy.ssl", "0.0.0.0")
user_pref("network.proxy.ssl_port", 80);
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);'


#Read in Prefsjs
$Prefsjs = (Get-Content $PrefsFiles)

#delete all the network proxy settings
foreach ($line in $Prefsjs){
if ($line -like 'user_pref("network.proxy.*') {$line = $null}

Else
{$out+= $line}
}




#add the whole chunk of proxy settings
foreach ($line in $out)
{
if ($line -like 'user_pref("network.cookie.prefsMigrated"*')
    {
    $out2+=$line+$Update
    }
    Else
        {
        $out2+= $line
        }
} 

$out2

#back up the existing file
Copy-Item $PrefsFiles $PrefsFiles".back"
#writeout the new file
Clear-Content $PrefsFiles
Add-Content $PrefsFiles $out2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Set-Content incorrectly.

From Microsoft's [Using the Set-Content Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176959.aspx)

> For example, this command writes the text “This is a test” to the text file C:\Scripts\Test.txt:
>
> **Set-Content c:\scripts\test.txt "This is a test"**

So with `Set-Content $PrefsFiles`, you've specified no text/content to be written, and because of that it is setting the content of the file to nothing (making it blank).

You read the contents into $Prefsjs and then modify it, so you need to provide that as the content you want to write -- try:

```
Set-Content $PrefsFiles $Prefsjs
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless, I'm wrong Bill's answer doesn't iterate over all prefs.js, even though it loads them all. (?)

Please find below an updated code

---

```
$PrefsFiles = Get-Item -Path ($env:SystemDrive+"\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\prefs.js")
$currentDate=Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d-%Hh%M"

#clear screen
clear


# Go through all files
foreach ($file in $PrefsFiles) {
$path = Get-ItemProperty -Path $file
 Write-Output "editing $path"
    $out = @()

    #Clean selected values

    foreach ($line in Get-Content $file){


        if (-Not ($line.Contains('"network.proxy.type",')) -and -Not ($line.Contains('"security.sandbox.content.level",')) ) {

             $out+= $line     
        }
    }

    #Add new values
    $out+= 'user_pref("network.proxy.type", 4);'
    $out+= 'user_pref("security.sandbox.content.level", 2);'


    #back up the existing file
    Copy-Item $file $file$currentDate".txt"

    #writeout the new file
    Clear-Content $file
    Add-Content $file $out

    Write-Output "Updated $path"

}
```